# Returning a value from a switch case

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This works (populating the generated drop-down menu):

```
$('dropdown_options').innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
jsonResponse.forEach(function(element){
    $('dropdown_options').innerHTML += '<option value='+ element.size + '>' element.size + '</option>';
});
```

But `element.size` is a number, and I need letters. Therefore I made the following function:

```
getLetterOfSizeNumber: function(number) {
        var size_letter = null;
        switch (number) {
        case 44: 
            size_letter = 'XS';
            break;
        case 45:
            size_letter = 'S';
            break;
        case 46:
            size_letter = 'M';
            break;
        case 47:
            size_letter = 'L';
            break;
        case 48:
            size_letter = 'XL';
            break;
        case 49:
            size_letter = 'XXL';
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return size_letter;
    }
```

and then I make it like that:

```
jsonResponse.forEach(function(element){
        $('dropdown_options').innerHTML += '<option value='+ element.size + '>' + myObject.getLetterOfSizeNumber(element.size) + '</option>';
```

And I get my drop-down populated with `null`s. Suggestions ?

Comment: Try returning before break

Comment: I think you are sending strings and not numbers. Try to change `case 44: ` to `case '44': ` .. etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a map instead

```
var numberToSize = {
    44: 'XS',
    45: 'S',
    46: 'M',
    47: 'L',
    48: 'XL',
    49: 'XXL'
};

// (or just remove the function altogether)
getLetterOfSizeNumber: function(number) {
    return numberToSize[number];
};
```

This will work for both numeric and string `number` values, because they're being used to access a property value.

Answer (score 1):

> And I get my drop-down populated with nulls. Suggestions ?

I would say your `element.size` returns a `string` , not a `number`. Thats why you got `null`.

Your code would work, if you use also strings in the case-expressions or alternative use `parseInt(element.size)` to get real a number.

But the more advance way is to use a object with the numbers as keys and the letters as values, like @Nico it described.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
 switch(number) { 
        case 44: 
           return 'XS';           
        case 45:
            return 'S';           
        case 46:
            return 'M';          
        case 47:
            return 'L';           
        case 48:
           return = 'XL';         
        case 49:
           return 'XXL';
        default:
            return '';
}
```